# Custom UITableViewCell - Add margin between each cell

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is it possible to apply a margin between UITableView cells?

The brief requires the table cells to look like below -

[image]

I have a custom cell class to style the background / fonts / separate labels -   but cannot figure out how to apply any kind of spacing!

Answer (score 9):

I woud do it the following way: first, make sure `background` color for both your `UITableViewCell` and its `contentView` is `[UIColor clearColor]`, then add a subview slightly smaller than your cell `contentView` (so that `height = CGRectGetHeight(contentView) - margin`) and fill it with the color you need. Then set the `backgroundView` for your `UITableView` and this should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

The Best way to get space between two cells in TableView in Swift language.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    cell.contentView.backgroundColor=UIColor.clearColor()

    var whiteRoundedCornerView:UIView!
    whiteRoundedCornerView=UIView(frame: CGRectMake(5,10,self.view.bounds.width-10,120))
    whiteRoundedCornerView.backgroundColor=UIColor(red: 174/255.0, green: 174/255.0, blue: 174/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.masksToBounds=false
    whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.55
    whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 0);
    whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.shadowColor=UIColor(red: 53/255.0, green: 143/255.0, blue: 185/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.cornerRadius=3.0
    whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.shadowOffset=CGSizeMake(-1, -1)
    whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.shadowOpacity=0.5
    cell.contentView.addSubview(whiteRoundedCornerView)
    cell.contentView.sendSubviewToBack(whiteRoundedCornerView)
}
```

Answer (score -4):

for the margin of the cell inside cell class's layoutSubviews() funs add this code line.

```
contentView.frame = contentView.frame.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10))
```